# SQL syntax error throwing near "CLUSTERED": syntax error

Tags: ios, sql, swift, sqlite, opaque-pointers

While loading sql query its throwing error

**near "CLUSTERED": syntax error**

```
import SQLite3
var db: OpaquePointer?
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("HeroesDatabase.sqlite")
        if sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) != SQLITE_OK {
            print("error opening database")
        }
        let sqlString = """
            CREATE TABLE Dim_Date
        (Calendar_Date DATE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Dim_Date PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,Calendar_Date_String VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)
        """


 if sqlite3_exec(db, sqlString, nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("error creating table: \(errmsg)")//Here Error throws
        }
```

Actually i am trying to achieve this https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/

Comment: `CLUSTERED` is not a SQLite keyword.  If you want a table with a clustered index, then use a `WITHOUT ROWID` table, if you're using SQLite version 3.8.2 or later.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please put SQL query as comment. I am newbee hence i need helping hand.

Comment: Just read the accepted answer from the duplicate link.  I didn't think it was worth paraphrasing that answer in my own answer here.